# CPython from Java?

Tags: java, python, numpy, jython, cpython

I need to call CPython code from Java. What tools/APIs/libraries exist out there to help me do this?

Jython is not an option since the Python code is heavily dependent upon `numpy`.

edit 1: The `main()` function should be Java, not Python (i.e. I need to embed CPython into Java, not vice versa.)

edit 2: I should also mention that I'll be passing large numeric arrays between Java and Python and therefore a solution that brings the two into the same process space would be preferable (but not mandatory.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at using [Jepp](http://jepp.sourceforge.net/) to embed CPython into Java. Read [documentation here](http://jepp.sourceforge.net/usage.html).

edit: For windows the project has prebuilt binaries for Python 2.4, 2.5, and 2.6. For Linux/Unix systems, you have to build it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to read the [docs on embedding a CPython interpreter](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html). Also, on how to load native libraries in Java (was that called [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)?)

Comment: Thanks. As it happens, I am reasonably familiar both with extending/embedding CPython, and with JNI. However, I view doing things this way as the last resort due to the amount of work it'll require for every function/class I'll be exposing from CPython to Java. I was hoping some work has already been done by others to help ease the pain.